Get All Users from the Azure Directory using Graph API in C#
I tried it is works fine, but I am getting only 100 users.
C# Code:
    public async Task getAllUsers()
    {
        UserCollectionResponse users = await GraphClient.Users.GetAsync();

        foreach (var item in users.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("item.UserPrincipalName");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(users.Value.Count);
    }

Users Count in showing at the last line

How can it be done?

By default, Microsoft Graph API returns a maximum of 100 items per request. However, you can increase the page size up to a maximum of 999 items per request by using the $top parameter in your API requests. You need to make use of $top parameter to your request URL

@Rukmini I knew that and I tried some solution but that doesn't works.

How did you include $top in your code?

I didn't tried with $top but I tried with users.OdataNextLink, this is return some URL, but I not getting what should I do next.

public async Task getAllUsers()
{
try
{
UserCollectionResponse users = await GraphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999;
});
foreach (var item in users.Value)
{
Console.WriteLine($"User Principal Name: {item.UserPrincipalName}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"Total users: {users.Value.Count}");
}

Yes, That's Works, but I have more than 999 users in site, so how can do it.

Then you have to make use of @odata. nextLink field

An article on how to iterate through the pages with the Graph SDK can be found here

You can refer this for sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp#manually-requesting-subsequent-pages

while (users?.Value != null)
{
foreach (var user in users.Value)
{
Console.WriteLine(users);
}
// If OdataNextLink has a value, there is another page
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(users.OdataNextLink))
{
    // Pass the OdataNextLink to the WithUrl method
    // to request the next page
    users = await GraphClient.Users.WithUrl(users.OdataNextLink).GetAsync();
}
else
{
    // No more results, exit loop
    break;
}

}

After     public async Task getAllUsers()
{
try
{
UserCollectionResponse users = await GraphClient.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
{
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 100;
}); ADD WHILE BLOCK

@Rukmini while loop is going to infinite.

Did you check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp#manually-requesting-subsequent-pages

Did you do the same? I am unable to reproduce as I do not have more users in my environment

No, I tried myself, your reference urls helps me lot.

Can I post it as an answer?

yes you can post it.

Note that: By default Microsoft Graph API returns a maximum of 100 items per request. You can increase the page size up to a maximum of 999 items per request by using the $top parameter in your API requests. You need to make use of $top parameter to your request URL.
To make use of  $top parameter to your request URL, modify the code like below:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;


namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task getAllUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                UserCollectionResponse users = await GraphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999;
                });

                foreach (var item in users.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"User Principal Name: {item.UserPrincipalName}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Total users: {users.Value.Count}");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user details: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            GraphHandler handler = new GraphHandler();

            await handler.getAllUsers();
        }
    }
}


If you want to print more that 999 items per request, you need to print @odata.nextLink property and request the next page by adding code snippet to the class something like below:
while (users?.Value != null)  
{  
foreach (var user in users.Value)  
{  
Console.WriteLine(users);  
}

// If OdataNextLink has a value, there is another page  
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(users.OdataNextLink))  
{  
// Pass the OdataNextLink to the WithUrl method  
// to request the next page  
users = await GraphClient.Users.WithUrl(users.OdataNextLink).GetAsync();  
}  
else  
{  
// No more results, exit loop  
break;  
}  
}

Reference:
Page through a collection using the Microsoft Graph SDKs - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft

This is just give us to top 999 users.

Yes to get more than 999 users you need to print @odata.nextLink property and request the next page

@AshishPrajapati I have added the reference in the end of the answer as I do not have more users to reproduce

Client-side Pagination in Grpah API
I hope you need do pagination to get all the user details from Graph API.
Graph API supports OData Query parameters, like $count, $expand, $filter, $orderby, $search, $select, and $top. The important point to not here is that you need to use $top and not $skip to do pagination. The microsoft documentation states as below

Support for client-side paging, including the number of results that the client can request for in a single page depends on the API and the query being performed. For example, the /users endpoint supports $top but not $skip.

This is how you need to the pagination to get 50 users per request

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=50
The response of #1 will provide the @odata.nextLink whcih you can used to call the next 50 users
Repeat the iteration till you get @odata.nextLink as empty value

Rererences
Graph REST API - Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app
Graph REST API - Page through a collection using the Microsoft Graph SDKs
Graph REST API - List Users
You can also refer how pagination can be done using Graph SDK client assembly here
